# how to Select value from another table in room database query (use in where)

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-jetpack

I want to use value from another table in room query (use in where).

this is `DAO`.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM  tbl_push a Where :whereQuery order by id Desc")
        Flowable<List<Push>> Message_SelectAll_forFiltering(String whereQuery);
```

and for `whereQuery` I used this code in `viewModel` (`whereQuery` is changeable):

```
    whereQuery= "and a.Id IN (Select pushId From tbl_pushtag where TagId IN(" + tagItemsId + "))";
```

But second query does not work!!!